# DataTables doesn't search certain column values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a data dependent dropdown

- First select menu picked - datatables gets filtered on Column 6 and the second select menu gets filtered accordingly
- Second menu gets picked - datatables gets filtered on Column 7

JS

```
$('#department-list').on('change', function(){
    table.ajax.reload();
    table.columns( 6 ).search( this.value ).draw();   
    table.columns( 7 ).search( "" ).draw();     
});
$('#team-list').on('change', function(){
    table.columns( 7 ).search( this.value ).draw(); 
});
```

So I know Column 7 has the following:

- MHGS
- Response Team A
- Response Team B
- Response Team C
- Response Team D
- Response Team E

It only seems to work on B, C and D. When selecting A or E, nothing seems to change.

I've done an alert on the 2nd clause above and it alerts what I expect it to. I also have filters on the columns as below and when I select `Response Team A` (or E), it filters as expected

```
initComplete: function () {
    var filterColumns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    table.columns(filterColumns).every(function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
        .on( 'change', function () {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
            column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
        } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
```

Any reason

Answer (score 0):

```
table.columns( 7 ).search( this.value, false, false ).draw();
```

From https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Switched off smart search